# Express: Add middleware on static folder

Tags: node.js, express

Hello I have express app where i need to plug a custom middleware/logic before accessing static folder for serving files, how i can achieve that without applying this middleware on every route. For now code looks like:

```
function middleware() {
  console.log('hello');
}

app.use(middleware).use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('server running on 8000');
});

app.get('/hi', (req, res) => {});
```

Issue is when **hi** is called middleware is executed as well and I want to execute it only if static files from public folder are called

Comment: There is a contradiction in your question. You say I want to execute something BEFORE static middleware, but I want it only happen if static middleware decides to serve a file.

Answer (score 1):

first of all create a middleware.js in the middleware you can impalement business logic

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  let substring = ".html"; // static files
  if (req.originalUrl.includes(substring)) {
    console.log("hello");
  }
  next();
};
```

in app.js

```
const middleware = require('./middleware');

app.use(middleware).use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('server running on 8000');
});

app.get('/hi', (req, res) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options:

1. either your middleware first checks that the requested file exists

   ```
    app.get('*', myMiddleware, express.static('public'))
   ```
2. or you run your middleware and static middleware if the path LOOKS like the static

   ```
    app.get('*(png|jpg|css)', myMiddleware, express.static('public'))
   ```

In both cases you can chain middlewares together (note multiple params in `app.get`). So that they are executed in this order and you can control the chain by using `next()` and `next('route')`

Your middleware would look like this:

```
    function myMiddleware (req, res, next) {
      // optionally check if file exists depending if you take option 1
      if (/* file exist check based on req.path */) {
        // if file doesn't exit, go to next router
        next('route') // here 'route' is a magic word, see https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html
      }

      console.log('hi')
      next() // don't forget this!
    }
```

NOTE: `next('route')` in option 1 only works with `app.get` not simple `app.use`, but i hope you only need GET for your static